# Executing SQL Stored Procedure through Excel (VBA) with multiple parameters

Tags: vba, sql, parameters

Thanks for your help, @FreeMan.

However, I am still lost with this.

Let me just start from scratch.

This is my query in summary ( I hope it is clear)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Q1,Q2,Q3

from(SELECT A,B,C) Q1

full outer join

(SELECT A,B,C

from tblA as a

join tblB as b

on a.aID = b.bID

join tblC as c

on b.bID = c.cID

where (a,b, cdate <= ?

group by c) Q2

ON Q1.A = Q2.B

WHERE Convert(DATETIME, Q1.[B], 103) <= ?

order by Q1.[A]

When I try to refresh my table, I get the following error message

"[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Parameter number" and then

"[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index"
```

I need a method that will allow me to run this query using the parameters in a specified cell i.e. cell C3.

I hope this makes things a bit clearer I am not familiar with VBA so all the commands advised above are confusing to me.

**Original Question**

*[I am a newbie when it comes to VBA and so I am struggling to get my query to run with more than one parameter.
I am using this macro as but when I run it it tells me the second parameter has not been provided.

```
Sub RefreshQuery()

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MYSERVER").OLEDBConnection
    .CommandText = "EXECUTE dbo.Tng_Market_Feed '" & Range("B2").Value & "'"
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MYSERVER").Refresh

End Sub
```

My questions are:-
1. How do I set the variables to date formats? I need a report to show me all transactions <= a certain date (variable parameter)
2. The location of the variable in the spreadsheet, cell b2, remains the same for both parameters. For example, I need a list of all transactions <= 31/12/2014 and a value/sum of bad debt provision as at the same date 31/12/2014.]*

Comment: You want the macro to update the spreadsheet from a db? Or you want the macro to do something in the db itself?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sample of creating and setting parameters from within your code:

```
Sub CreateParam()

     Dim oQuery As QueryTable
     Dim oParam As Parameter

     Set oQuery = Sheet3.QueryTables(1)

     oQuery.CommandText = Replace(oQuery.CommandText, "='Berlin'", "=?")

     Set oParam = oQuery.Parameters.Add("CityParam")

     oParam.SetParam xlRange, Sheet3.Range("J1")
     oParam.RefreshOnChange = True

     oQuery.Refresh

End Sub
```

<sup>code quickly cribbed from [dicks-clicks.com](http://www.dicks-clicks.com/excel/ExternalData6.htm)</sup>

Basically you'll need to execute the `.Parameter.Add()` line for each parameter in your stored procedure, and you'll be good to go. Note that you don't need to write a whole `Sub()` to do it, you can just include the `Set oParam = oQuery.Parameters.Add()` line in your existing code.

You may want to dig into the the options a bit, because you can specify the type of data being sent, and can also set up an `OUT` parameter, as well, to accept data back from the query.

Comment: Thanks for your response, FreeMan. Apologies, but I seem to have omitted the fact that I am trying to create a macro that will execute a stored procedure within SQL which has more than one parameter.

Comment: @kiki - I got that part... Read the first paragraph below the code. Especially the first sentence.